# Multiple-column based lookups in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

```
        A     B    C
    1 PROD1 TYPE1 VAL1
    2 PROD2 TYPE1 VAL2
    3 PROD1 TYPE2 VAL3
    4 PROD2 TYPE3 VAL2
```

In an empty cell I want to get the value in C column for the Prod Type= Prod2 and type = type3.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at using the [DGET](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090591033.aspx) Excel function.

Set

- A1 = ProdType
- B1 = Type
- C1 = Val

*Then your provided data in A2:C5*

Then

- H1 = ProdType
- I1 = Type
- H2 = `=PROD2` (Criteria 1)
- I2 = `=TYPE3` (Criteria 2)

And lastly, in H3:

```
=DGET(A1:C5,"Val",H1:I2)
```

That should get the value for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4="PROD2")*($B$1:$B$4="TYPE3")*($C$1:$C$4))
```

This assumes that column C values are actually numbers and not text.

Answer (score 1):

**An improvement** on [the solution by Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967291/2707864) for the case when the output column does not contain numbers is

```
=INDEX(C:C,SUMPRODUCT((A:A="PROD2")*(B:B="TYPE3")*ROW(C:C)),0)
```

Taken from [here](http://blogs.office.com/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582535/2707864).